# What do I need to install on remote linux server to be able connect it with ssh -X?

Tags: debian, remote-desktop

there is no graphics environment, it was configured to be accessed and managed via command-line.
It is Debian however I think the question is general for all distributions...
I was about to install xorg however many of "extra packages that will be installed" was clearly graphics-card drivers...

Comment: Install the desktop environment of your choice - my personal preference is xfce4.

Comment: I think I don't need whole desktop environment on remote machine without any display connected to it, do I? I will only start some apps. which need to use GUI. In this case oracle database installer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need the individual application's dependencies. I usually also install the `xauth` package (whatever name it goes by in your distribution of choice) so I can use the `-Y` option (note that `-X` may not be sufficient - you may have to use `-Y` instead) instead of exporting a `DISPLAY` variable.

Comment: Definitely use -Y (trusted X11 forwarding) instead of -X since it's more secure.